# Convert IEnumerable to List of properties

Tags: c#, linq, list, properties, ienumerable

Say I have a class called Event:

```
public class Event
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And have the following query:

```
var events = _eventInformationRepository.Fetch(e => e.Id != -1);
```

Which returns an `IEnumerable<Event>`. But I'd like to create a list of IDs of events. Can this be done directly via ienum? Or do I have to generate the list, iterate, assign and add each value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the Linq [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) method:

```
var events = ...
var eventIDs = events.Select(e => e.Id);
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<int>`, which should be enough for most purposes. However, if you really want a `List<int>` you can just call the [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) method:

```
var eventIDs = events.Select(e => e.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: Wow, felt so stupid to have missed Select! Yes, I need to cast to List since I will use it to validate another query/ienum. Thanks again!